# bindWithEvent error while converting mooRainbow to mootools 1.4.4

Tags: javascript, events, mootools

I'm trying to get mooRainbow 1.2b ( http://moorainbow.woolly-sheep.net/ ) working with mootools 1.4.4 and I've run into an error that I can't seem to find an answer for.

### The error is thrown in this section...

---

```
OverlayEvents: function ()
{
    var lim, curH, curW, inputs;
    curH = this.snippet('curSize', 'int').h;
    curW = this.snippet('curSize', 'int').w;

    // $A is deprecated, the original line here was:
    // inputs = $A(this.arrRGB).concat(this.arrHSB, this.hexInput);

    inputs = this.arrRGB.concat(this.arrHSB, this.hexInput);

    document.addEvent('click', function ()
    {
        if (this.visible) this.hide(this.layout);
    }.bind(this));

    inputs.each(function (el)
    {
```

---

```
        // this is where the error is thrown
        el.addEvent('keydown', this.eventKeydown.bindWithEvent(this, el));
        el.addEvent('keyup', this.eventKeyup.bindWithEvent(this, el));
```

---

```
    }, this);
    [this.element, this.layout].each(function (el)
    {
        el.addEvents({
            'click': function (e) { new Event(e).stop(); },
            'keyup': function (e)
            {
                e = new Event(e);
                if (e.key == 'esc' && this.visible) this.hide(this.layout);
            }.bind(this)
        }, this);
    }, this);
```

---

### Here is the error that's thrown...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){
if (method.$protected && this.$caller == null) 
throw new Error('The method "' + key + '" cannot be called.');
var caller = this.caller, current = this.$caller;
this.caller = current; this.$caller = wrapper;
var result = method.apply(this, arguments);
this.$caller = current; this.caller = caller;
return result;
} has no method 'bindWithEvent'
```

PS. The problem seems similar to the one here [MooTools/JS: bindWithEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972235/mootools-js-bindwithevent) but the answers there are irrelevant to my context and I'm not sure if it is the same issue or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062839/how-to-replace-bindwithevent-in-mootools-1-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

long time no speak mate (coda here). get back to IRC!

You really need to look at the funcs themselves. often they are not really optimal and rely too many arguments and setting up.

possible workarounds for deprecated bindWithEvent can be...

## 1 replace this...

```
el.addEvent('keydown', this.eventKeydown.bindWithEvent(this, el));
el.addEvent('keyup', this.eventKeyup.bindWithEvent(this, el));
```

... with something like:

```
el.addEvents({
    keyup: this.eventKeyup.bind(this),
    keydown: this.eventKeydown.bind(this)
});
```

then in the 2 event funcs, argument 1 will be event. `el == event.target` - that's one pattern

## 2 curry ftw

proxy in an anon function.

```
var self = this;
el.addEvent("keyup", function(e) {
    self.eventKeyup(e, this);    
});
```

## 3 ... etc etc. sky's the limit.

Comment: thanks! i should definitely get back on IRC, I tried the first option and it worked, that's the way I've been doing events in my own code I just didnt know what was up with bindWithEvent :)